# iTunesConnect - How to retrieve 1024x1024 icon of an existing app?

Tags: app-store, appstore-approval, ios11, xcode9, asset-catalog

I've noticed that since iOS 11, the App's "App Icon" asset in the catalog must include a 1024x1024 sized version in order to be submitted to the App Store.

I know that the 1024x1024 icon was previously added directly to the iTunesConnect app page, but I can not seem to get any link or a way to display that icon in full size to grab it from the iTunesConnect page.

**How can I retrieve the existing 1024x1024 icon for an app already published?** I do not have the PSD file for the original icon.

> Dear developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for
>   [App]. Your delivery was successful, but you may wish to correct the
>   following issues in your next delivery:
>
> Missing Marketing Icon - iOS Apps must include a 1024x1024px Marketing
>   Icon in PNG format. **Apps that do not include the Marketing Icon
>   cannot be submitted for App Review or Beta App Review.**
>
> After you’ve corrected the issues, you can use Xcode or Application
>   Loader to upload a new binary to iTunes Connect.
>
> Regards,
>
> The App Store team

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**EDIT:** I made a simple tool for this:
https://erkanyildiz.me/lab/icon1024/

---

Go to your app's iTunes page:
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/MyApp/id000000000

Find the URL for your app's icon in the page inspecting source code.
It should be in this format:

`http://isN.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple128/v4/xx/yy/zz/xxyyzzaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa/source/175x175bb.jpg`

Replace last `175x175` part with `1024x1024` and `jpg` part with `png`:

`http://isN.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple128/v4/xx/yy/zz/xxyyzzaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa/source/1024x1024bb.png`

Now you can get the original icon.

Note: 
Those 2 chars after dimension are used as `Image Resize Style`.

`bb`: you can specify any dimension you want, it will return a resized version for dimensions less than `1024x1024`. But, if you specify a dimension larger than `1024x1024`, it will return `1024x1024` anyway.

`cc`: it will return the dimension you specify.

`ff`: it also seems to be a valid option, but I have no idea what it does.

`ss`: another valid option, and again no idea.

Comment: Thanks - worked like a charm. There are 22 places where similar icons are used - look for your app name over the icon